# Does spinning from a different side from your jumps affects your skating?

Tags: ice-skating, figure-skating

As the title say I'm spinning from a different directions than when I jump, it's way more natural and easy to spin to the right while landing on my right foot.

I had two separate advices from two coaches, one said I had to learn to spin to the left since it could be problematic on some figures and the other said to not change anything and adapt to skate like this since it's more natural for me.

I am a bit confused if this would affect me in my progression or during a competition, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Conventional wisdom is that you must jump and spin in the same direction.  https://www.thoughtco.com/direction-figure-skaters-jump-and-spin-1282268.  In general I always find this coach's advice really good.  In my own coaching, I am a proponent of developing skills leading with both the dominant and the non-dominant foot specifically because sometimes the situation will need you to lead with your non-dominate foot.  On the other hand, at some point "you have to do you" and I've received advice telling me to find ways to accommodate my own idiosyncrasies but I think that comes after a good faith effort to follow conventional wisdom.